# Cross-site scripting vulnerability because of a CNAME entry

Tags: security, xss, cname

One of our advertising networks for a site I administer and develop is requesting the following:

> We have been working on increasing performance on XXXX.com and our team feels that if we can set up the following CNAME on that domain it will help increase rates:
>
> srv.XXXX.com d2xf3n3fltc6dl.XXXX.net
>
> Could you create this record with your domain registrar? The reason we need you to create this CNAME is to preserve domain transparency within our RTB. Once we get this setup I will make some modifications in your account that should have some great results.*

Would this not open up our site to cross-site scripting vulnerabilities? Wouldn't malicious code be able to masquerade as coming from our site to bypass same-origin policy protection in browsers? I questioned him on this and this was his response:

> First off let me address the benefits. The reason we would like you to create this CNAME is to increase domain transparency within our RTB. Many times when ads are fired, JS is used to scrape the URL and pass it to the buyer. We have found this method to be inefficient because sometimes the domain information does not reach the market place. This causes an impression (or hit) to show up as “uncategorized” rather than as “XXXX.com” and this results in lower rates because buyer pay up to 80% less for uncategorized inventory. By creating the CNAME we are ensuring that your domain shows up 100% of the time and we usually see CPM and revenue increases of 15-40% as a result.
> I am sure you are asking yourself why other ad networks don’t do this. The reason is that this is not a very scalable solution, because as you can see, we have to work with each publisher to get this setup. Unlike big box providers like Adsense and Lijit, OURCOMPANY is focused on maximizing revenue for a smaller amount of quality publishers, rather than just getting our tags live on as many sites as possible. We take the time and effort to offer these kinds of solutions to maximize revenue for all parties.
> In terms of security risks, they are minimal to none. You will simply be pointing a subdomain of XXXX.com to our ad creative server. We can’t use this to run scripts on your site, or access your site in any way.
> Adding the CNAME is entirely up to you. We will still work our hardest to get the best rates possible, with or without that. We have just seen great results with this for other publishers, so I thought that I would reach out and see if it was something you were interested in.

This whole situation raised red flags with me but is really outside of my knowledge of security. Can anyone offer any insight to this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would enable cookies set at the `XXXX.com` level to be read by each site, but it would not allow other [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) actions unless both sites opt in. Both sites would have to set `document.domain = 'XXXX.com';` in client-side script to allow access to both domains.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.domain):

> Mozilla distinguishes a document.domain property that has never been set from one explicitly set to the same domain as the document's URL, even though the property returns the same value in both cases. One document is allowed to access another if they have both set `document.domain` to the same value, indicating their intent to cooperate, or neither has set `document.domain` and the domains in the URLs are the same (implementation). Were it not for this special policy, every site would be subject to XSS from its subdomains (for example, `https://bugzilla.mozilla.org` could be attacked by bug attachments on `https://bug*.bugzilla.mozilla.org`).